# Multi author CMS

Tags: cms

I'm looking for a multi-author website/blog platform as part of school activities, so everyone can share his experience by posting blogpost.

---

- Hosting must be free (or really cheap considering it will be online at most 6 months)
- Manage 40+ users
- Admin controls users registrations (Only registered users are allowed to post)
- Posts may contain picture
- Anyone can see everyone posts (even unregistered users)
- Track users statistics (Number of posts, ...)
- Clear UI for users

---

These features are necessary, any other extra features are welcome. But every ideas is good to take even if they don't meet every criteria.

Comment: Sounds to me like almost any blog (or blog hosting service) would be suitable for your case. -- Maybe specifying what exactly you understand under "Track users statistics" could narrow it down. Showing the number of posts is probably no problem; anything else? And should the stats only be visible to the admin?

Comment: Join date and last activity would be a plus under the User Statistics criteria, and would be visible to everyone (registered or not), and a list of every post created by the user.

Is there any out of the box solutions beside WordPress (no free hosting) ?

Comment: https://wordpress.com/ offers gratis hosting of WordPress instances (or do I misunderstand you?). However, they don’t allow to install plugins, so the user statistics might not be possible (apart from a simple per-author list of posts, which is the default, I guess).